# Strange border glitch of an ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift3

I made a custom view containing some imageviews. But they have a strange border glitch: there is an offset from the edge of the image revealing some background colour.

[image]

This is how I make image views:

```
        for (index, image) in self.images.enumerated()
        {
            if index == maxIndex {
                break
            }

            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: offsetX, y: 0, width: self.height, height: self.height))
            imageView.cornerRadius = self.height / 2
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imageView.image = image
            imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
            self.addSubview(imageView)
            self.imageViews.append(imageView)

            offsetX += self.height / 2 + 5
        }
```

There are no views under imageviews. Subviews count is 4

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What _are_ you asking? Where is the "glitch" you are talking about? What's the question?

Comment: @matt The white border has a small offset from the edge

Comment: So your problem is that the thick "ring" around the outside of the images is not intentional? Is that it? Could you should a picture of what you actually want to do? Or at least describe it?

Comment: I suppose the issue is that there is a thin ring of underlying image outside white border.

Comment: @matt The code describes it perfectly. I need a white border around each image. But for some reason the border has an offset from the edge of the image.

Comment: "The code describes it perfectly" If it did, you'd get what you wanted. There is no "white" in your code anywhere! So what "white border" are you even talking about? I am mystified by what you say and I still cannot guess what you want.

Comment: @matt Thanks for your 'help', but I already got an answer. Have a nice day

Comment: But you see, in that answer _there is white_ (`white.cgColor`). Your code had no "white". That is why it was hard to guess where the white was supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an aliasing issue. Some edge pixels of border are semi-transparent and because of that you can see the underlaying content.

You can try adding a custom CAShapeLayer with circle path:

```
let border = CAShapeLayer()
border.frame = imageView.bounds
border.lineWidth = 4 //doubled width
border.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: border.bounds).cgPath
border.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
border.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
imageView.layer.addSublayer(border)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Widening didn't help. I will try the custom layer.